# Uso de Timezones com plugin Moment

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

Estou com dificuldades em utilizar o plugin Timezones da biblioteca Moment.js, mais especificamente, não estou conseguindo carregar os dados.
Preciso carregar os *timezones* de Londres e de São Paulo, mas não consegui entender muito bem aquele [formato da documentação](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/):

```
moment.tz.add([
    'America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0',
    'America/New_York|EST EDT|50 40|0101|1Lz50 1zb0 Op0'
]);
```

Ali tem o exemplo, mas que siglas e números são estes? Quais são os de Londres e São Paulo?

Procurei na documentação os dados disponíveis, mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver abrindo um [*issue* no projeto](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/207#issuecomment-96838711). Segue a solução:

---

### Tradução livre:

A documentação está [aqui](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/), mas eu concordo que ela poderia ser mais completa. Nós também estamos esperando o [Data Builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) por [#9](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/9).

O maneira mais fácil por enquanto é incluir um dos dois arquivos disponível na [página inicial do moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), o `moment-timezone-2010-2020.js` ou`moment-timezone-all-years.js`.

Se você quer apenas zonas específicas, então use `moment-timezone.js`, e extraia as zonas que você precisa dos outros arquivos de dados, ou do arquivo [`latest.json`](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json) no GitHub.

Para 2010-2020 apenas:

```
moment.tz.add([
   "America/Sao_Paulo|BRST BRT|20 30|01010101010101010101010|1BIq0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 Rb0 1zd0 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10",
   "Europe/London|GMT BST|0 -10|01010101010101010101010|1BWp0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00"
]);
```

Para todos os anos:

```
moment.tz.add([
   "America/Sao_Paulo|LMT BRT BRST|36.s 30 20|012121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212|-2glwR.w HdKR.w 1cc0 1e10 1bX0 Ezd0 So0 1vA0 Mn0 1BB0 ML0 1BB0 zX0 pTd0 PX0 2ep0 nz0 1C10 zX0 1C10 LX0 1C10 Mn0 H210 Rb0 1tB0 IL0 1Fd0 FX0 1EN0 FX0 1HB0 Lz0 1EN0 Lz0 1C10 IL0 1HB0 Db0 1HB0 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 Lz0 1zd0 Rb0 1wN0 Wn0 1tB0 Rb0 1tB0 WL0 1tB0 Rb0 1zd0 On0 1HB0 FX0 1C10 Lz0 1Ip0 HX0 1zd0 On0 1HB0 IL0 1wp0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 Rb0 1zd0 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 Rb0 1wp0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1zd0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0 Rb0 1wp0 On0 1C10 Lz0 1C10 On0 1zd0",
   "Europe/London|GMT BST BDST|0 -10 -20|0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010121212121210101210101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010|-2axa0 Rc0 1fA0 14M0 1fc0 1g00 1co0 1dc0 1co0 1oo0 1400 1dc0 19A0 1io0 1io0 WM0 1o00 14o0 1o00 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1lc0 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1cM0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 1qM0 Dc0 2Rz0 Dc0 1zc0 Oo0 1zc0 Rc0 1wo0 17c0 1iM0 FA0 xB0 1fA0 1a00 14o0 bb0 LA0 xB0 Rc0 1wo0 11A0 1o00 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1fA0 1cM0 1fA0 1a00 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 17c0 1lc0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1io0 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fA0 1a00 1a00 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1tA0 IM0 90o0 U00 1tA0 U00 1tA0 U00 1tA0 U00 1tA0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1tA0 U00 1tA0 U00 1tA0 11z0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 14o0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00"
]);
```

Comment: Pela referência de `latest.json` encontrei uma maneira de colocar abreviação na timezone de Manaus que precisava (AMT)